# What is the reason why Microsoft decided not to provide updates when bypassing TPM requirements?

Tags: windows, tpm

I understand TPM is quite an important tool for security, but a lot of the updates not being offered should not be related to TPM. Not offering updates to people who bypass TPM on Windows 11 and also providing information on how to bypass TPM seems strange to me. Looked around for an answer, but there doesn't seem anything official.

Comment: Microsoft provides updates to Windows 11 installations that are bypassing the TPM requirement. What Microsoft does is they say that pontentially in future it may happen that such systems not passing all requirements may get no updates after a certain point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does Microsoft say they *won't* provide updates? The [KB Doc about installing on unsupported systems](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/installing-windows-11-on-devices-that-don-t-meet-minimum-system-requirements-0b2dc4a2-5933-4ad4-9c09-ef0a331518f1) says:

> Devices [..] will no longer be *guaranteed* to receive updates

They want to use capabilities of modern TPMs in future updates. That's why there are those restrictions and why it is not recommended to install on unsupported systems. In case you have a PC without a compatible TPM, those new features won't work on your PC and therefore you won't receive those updates. But they aren't actively kicking out computers from their update mechanisms, as far as I know.

Comment: I wonder what MS will do with all the PC's that does not meet Windows 11's hardware requirements after 2025 when they end Windows 10. I mean, there would be millions computers. A lot of people probably will not buy a new PC to use Windows 11.